# What software can I use to prevent some startup programs from running?

Tags: windows-7

[image]

I keep seeing that program on my computer, what is that? I tried to disable all startup(via registry) and Startup folder in Start menu. But that program keeps popping up during windows start. It appears above the traybar's clock. And also, what's the best software for disabling startup programs?

Comment: eIts impossible to see what the image is.

Comment: That's why I asked. Maybe others have encountered the same program, malware or otherwise

Comment: its that small? could you post a full screenshot, of the whole screen? and also one with it magnified with the magnification option in windows 7? (hit windows key and +)

Comment: It just appear momentarily during startup, at the rightmost bottom of the screen(i.e. near the clock). Most Windows programs' icons/images are raster ones, any magnification won't help

Comment: The Autoruns advised by Mehrdad helps. I tried disabling some of the programs one by one, apparently, the program is **C:\program files (x86)\cobian backup 10\cbinterface.exe**. That image don't appear anymore when I disabled cbinterface.exe. I'm just wondering why it changed to that image, Cobian Backup uses mushroom logo before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902), by Microsoft, to disable the startup of the program.

If you literally need to *prevent* a certain executable from running, you might need to set a Group Policy based on the file hash, to block the file. But that's only on Windows 7 Professional and above, and you might as well just delete the executable instead (it's a lot easier).

Comment: +1 for being what i'd suggest. but we still don't know what exactly he's trying to block. Some malware might re-enable itself and such.

Comment: @Journeyman: Yeah I have no idea really, the screenshot doesn't help either. I'm a bit hesitant to say it's malware, though, because I've seen programs (e.g. RealPlayer, Quicktime, etc.) re-enable themselves if you disable them the wrong way.

Comment: you might want to fix it - even 'view as' dosen't render anything that is visible